# Static positioned div box problem

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to have a div box in a static position meaning that when someone scrolls down the page, the div stays in the same position.

I have googled a lot and I found some solutions, but they were all using defined positions like top left, top right etc.. and I need a solution that will work regardless of the place the div is in. So basically the script needs to either take the current position and set that to the fixed position, or not work with fixed X/Y position..

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `position:fixed` for  your element.

**Example:**

```
#dv{
  position:fixed; /* this is important for you */
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background:blue;
}
```

### [Check out the example](http://jsbin.com/ojaxi5)

Notice that div remains there even if you scroll :)

Comment: This works great.. I wonder why all these people using long JS codes which I found on my Google search..

Comment: @Or W: Nice to know it helps you. Notice that `position:fixed` isn't supported in IE6 though :)

Comment: One thing though, the div box that I need to fix to a certain position is using float:right, whenever I add the position:fixed, it moves from the right to the left... is there a way to solve this?

Comment: @Or W: You could use `margin-left` with greater value for it.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Shaz/Fqr4t/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'regardless of the place the div is in', however, if you can't use position: fixed, there is an onscroll event in Javascript that you can hook into. You can update the position of the div there. Do note that this is usually isn't fast enough to look fluent.